# Is there an rpm for glibc static libraries built with -fPIC readily available for centos?

Tags: centos, glibc

Is there an rpm for centos glibc-static that is built with -fPIC?

I have a situation where I need to build a shared library without any dependencies. This includes having no dependency on the libraries included with glibc among others. I found the glibc-static rpm for centos [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/glibc-static-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) but these static libraries were not built using -fPIC so they are useless for creating a shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a situation where I need to build a shared library without any dependencies.

That is impossible when using GLIBC. *No matter what you do*, your shared library will depend on `libc.so.6` and `ld-linux.so`.

> This includes having no dependency on the libraries included with glibc among others.

Linking `libc.a` into your `.so` will *not* solve your problem (whatever that problem is, see http://xyproblem.info).